# showing sq lite data column wise by not using list view

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is there any way to show data from sq lite database in android application ,other than using list views? just like data s stored in the sq lite table , column by column .It must be editable to update the sq lite table.does any one know?

Comment: You should use a grid view. with edittext inside that

Comment: It's depend on which kind of data you need to show. Like image and text , only image , text and description. Rather than list view you can use Grid view , Card view , Recycler view.

Comment: i want it like a sheet. colums to show some values from database.some column have edit text to insert data..is it possible with grid view?

Comment: Not sure may be you can do with Grid View. Give a Try.